# How to create plugin in wordpress

Tags: plugins, customization

How to create plugin in wordpress

Answer (score 2):

Please have a look at the following links to get you started.

https://codex.wordpress.org/Writing_a_Plugin

https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/wordpress-plugin-development-guide/

https://www.elegantthemes.com/blog/tips-tricks/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin

http://www.wpbeginner.com/wp-tutorials/how-to-create-a-wordpress-plugin/

https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/create-a-custom-wordpress-plugin-from-scratch--net-2668

Answer (score 0):

- Please use WORDPRESS PLUGIN BOILERPLATE GENERATOR framework to create our own plugin in WordPress
- This framework created basic file structured and folder of plugin as per details you have added.
- Please refereed below link to create plugin basic file structured then you can easily add your code in file.
- URL : https://wppb.me/

Comment: Using frameworks to create plugins is no longer accepted by the WordPress Plugin Directory. https://wptavern.com/the-wordpress-plugin-directory-will-no-longer-accept-frameworks and https://make.wordpress.org/plugins/2016/03/01/please-do-not-submit-frameworks/